# How do I get Visual Studio 2015 to create public properties when hitting "Ctrl + ."?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, visual-studio-2015, access-modifiers

So I often write code where I have a model class and usually use the shortcut 'Ctrl + .' to give me the option to add a field or property to the class that I have typed out that does not yet exist.  IN VS 2010,2012,2013 etc it would create a public property I.E.

```
public decimal? adRevenuePercentPartnerSold { get; set; }
```

Where as now it creates it with an internal set

```
public decimal? adRevenuePercentPartnerSold { get; internal set; }
```

This drives me crazy as when I test an MVC action the property never gets set from a post so I always have to go in and fix each property it creates.

Comment: It generates a public one for me... do you have any other plugins installed?

Comment: Ah - it looks like it depends on where you generate it from, or what you're doing. If you generate it from a call to the setter, in the same class, it's fully public... generate it from a call to the getter elsewhere, it's public get / internal set. Interesting.

Comment: I wonder if this changed as it probably uses Roslyn to implement this now.  It is not a good behavior as it took me a while to figure out why some properties were not getting set when trying to do some basic CRUD

Comment: Well, it's not the behaviour *you* happen to desire - but it may well be exactly the behaviour others desire...